# Rails 7 respond_do Error ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to do a Ajax request in rails 7 when the form is submitted (when the button is pressed) it renders JavaScript

In my Stocks Controller I have:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController

    def search
        if params[:stock].present?
            @stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:stock])
           if @stock
                 respond_to do |format|
                     format.js {render partial: 'users/result'}
                end
           else
                flash[:alert] = "Please enter a valid symbol to search"
                redirect_to my_portfolio_path
           end
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Please enter a symbol to search"
            redirect_to my_portfolio_path
        end

    end

end
```

My Form I have:

```
<div class="search-area">
<h3>Search Stocks</h3>
<%= form_tag search_stock_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 noRightPad">
            <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", 
            autofocus: true, class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 noLeftPad">
            <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "btn btn-success" do %>
                <%= fa_icon "search 2x" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Error Message:
[image]

Thank you for your time.

**Update**
Controller Updated

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
respond_to :js

def search
    if params[:stock].present?
        @stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:stock])
       if @stock
        respond_to do |format|
            format.turbo_stream do
              render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(
                "results",
                partial: "users/result" # render any partial and remove js code.
              )
            end
          end
       else
            flash[:alert] = "Please enter a valid symbol to search"
            redirect_to my_portfolio_path
       end
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Please enter a symbol to search"
        redirect_to my_portfolio_path
    end

end
```

end

Form Tag

```
<%= form_tag search_stock_path, method: :get, data: {turbo_stream: true}, remote: true do %>
```

I have researched the 406 Not acceptable error in console but it says to add respond_to which I have done and still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to demystify the magic here, I've seen this question come up a lot.

Setup:

```bash
rails new rails_formats -c tailwind
cd rails_formats
bin/rails g scaffold stock name
bin/rails db:migrate
open http://localhost:3000/stocks/new
bin/dev
```

---

## Headers

Rails abstracts this out of the away so you don't have to deal with this. There are two headers that you just have to know:

#### [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

This is what you send to the server with your request, and what you send back with the response. For example, you can send multipart form data and get json as a response *(when you need to upload images to your api server)*.

#### [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)

This is what you want to get as a response. This is the one that determines what format block rails will run.

#### [Mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

It's what goes into *Accept* and *Content-Type* headers. *Rails* has a class to handle it:
*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html*

```rb
Mime::Type.register "text/vnd.hyper-stream.html", :hyper
# if you send this in Accept ^ header, then run this ^ format block

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  ActionController::Renderers.add :hyper do |html, options|
    # set response type if rendering ^ `render hyper: ..`
    self.content_type = Mime[:hyper] if media_type.nil?
    html
  end
end

# now you have your own format
format.hyper { render hyper: ... }
```

---

## Controller and Form

You know what headers to use, here is how to use them:

```html
<!-- app/views/stocks/_form.html.erb -->

<!-- disable Turbo for now so it doesn't interfere -->
<script type="module"> Turbo.session.drive = false </script>

<!-- make your own remote form -->
<div id="remote_response"></div>
<%= form_with model: stock, html: {onsubmit: "remote(event)"} do |form| %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

*Use event listeners and event delegation in real apps.

```js
<script charset="utf-8">
  function remote(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;

    fetch(form.action, {
      // headers: { "Accept": "text/html" },
      // headers: { "Accept": "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html" },
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
      method: form.method,
      body: new FormData(form),
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        document.querySelector("#remote_response").innerHTML = text;
      })
  }
</script>
```

```rb
def create
  puts "# CONTENT TYPE  | #{request.content_type}"  # what you sent
  puts "# ACCEPT        | #{request.accept}"        # what you want

  # Change Accept header in `fetch` to choose which format block to run
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html         { render html:         "Responded with html" }
    format.json         { render json:         "Responded with json" }
    format.js           { render js:           "console.log('railsujs')" }
    format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: "Responded with turbo stream" }
  end

  puts "# RESPONSE TYPE | #{response.content_type}" # what you get
end
```

---

## {remote: true}

`remote: true` (or `local: false` if using `form_with`) will add `data-remote="true"` to the form tag and that's it. Something on the frontend has to know what to do with it. That something is *RailsUJS* which was replaced by [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/) in *rails 7*.

```bash
$ bin/importmap pin @rails/ujs
```

Just pick Turbo or RailsUJS:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

// import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
// import "controllers"

import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
Rails.start();
```

```rb
<%= form_with model: stock, local: false do |form| %>
...
```

Now *RailsUJS* will do what we did with `remote()` function and set `Accept` to `text/javascript` so that `format.js` block would run. It will also handle the response and execute the code.

---

## Turbo

Streams and frames and broadcasts take a little bit to get your head around it. Just start with `turbo_stream` I found it much easier to understand at first.

No set up needed, all forms submit "remotely" as TURBO_STREAM format aka `"Accept": "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html, text/html, application/xhtml+xml"`. This means you can respond with `format.html` or `format.turbo_stream`.

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream do
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(
      "id_of_the_element_to_update",
      partial: "users/result" # render any partial and remove js code.
    )
  end
end
```

---

#### Update

***GET* streams**

Add `data-turbo-stream="true"` to forms with `method: :get` and links.

```rb
form_tag "/", method: :get, data: {turbo_stream: true} do
```

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#streaming-from-http-responses*

**Bootstrap**

You can't import "bootstrap" unless you have a pin for it:

```js
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
//                          ^^^^^^^^^
// browser doesn't know how to get that
```

Add a pin (and get styles from cdn):

```
bin/importmap pin bootstrap
```

If importmaps add too much hassle use `cssbundling-rails`. Rails has this built in:

```bash
rails new my_app -c bootstrap
```

But there are lots of other answers on how to install bootstrap in rails 7.

**Debug**

Working with javascript, you have to look at your browser console.

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is my code for a test I tried doign as you said but keep having the same error using turbo. I cannot see a Mime class https://github.com/kirnchakraborty/-finance-tracker

Comment: @Kirnc see update. also remove bootstrap scripts from your layout, you don't need three of them.

Comment: Hi Alex, last question the way you have done it  render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update( how do i specify the type format.js etc if i wanted multiple partials with the same name but different type. Thanks again

Comment: @Kirnc `formats: :js` i guess, should be the same options as for `render`. but you don't really need `js` format, `script` tags will execute anyway.